# OS X wants me to reset my password randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bootcamp

I restarted from Windows (under Boot Camp) via Restart in OS X..., which I've done many times before. This time, my MacBook restarted and stayed black for a while. I eventually held the power button to reboot it.

It eventually came back up to a Reset Password recovery screen. I tried restarting and holding Option to select the Macintosh partition, but it always comes back to Reset Password.

[image]

I didn't forget my password. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [Skip Reset Password for OS X](https://schwartzmeyer.com/2015/03/21/skip-reset-password-for-os-x/)

> OS X Yosemite has a troublesome password reset screen you can access by turning your computer off and back on from the login screen. **However, once you do this, there is no way out.** The "Reset Password" boot wizard offers no exit without reseting your password. If you restart your Mac, you will end up right back in the wizard.

The solution is a PRAM reset: `Command-Option-P-R` during bootup.